# Concatenate child table rows in parent's new column in PowerBi / PowerQuery

Tags: excel, report, powerbi, powerquery

i'm trying to achieve this report with powerquery:

parent - child related table transformation

[image]

I thought that it will be a very simple "Table.SelectRows('ChildTable', each [Id] = [ParentId])" followed by a concatenation... but i can't get it work. SelectRows function expects literal as comparator and i'm not able to find a workaroud.

Any help is appresiated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way: Merge your two tables, set up like this...

[image]

and you'll see this...

[image]

Then add a new Custom Column, set up like this...

[image]

and you'll see this...

[image]

Then click the button to expand or extract the List values in the Custom column, and click on "Extract Values..."

[image]

and select to use a Comma as a delimiter...

[image]

and you'll see this...

[image]

Then you can rename the Custom column to ChildNames and delete the Id and ChildTable columns to end up with what you want...

[image]